# Роутинг не работает на хостинге. PHP

Tags: php, ооп, роутинг

Ребят, прохожу курс ООП PHP у одного парня. Учит писать блог на ООП.
Затык с работой роутинга на хостинге beget. На OpenServer все работает. 
Парень утверждает, что все работает, но уже 3 бьюсь, чтобы заработало и ничего.
Может, у кого идеи будут. Код и структура папок как на хостинге: https://github.com/prognoz2019/blog
Ошибка:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/p/site/site.beget.tech/public_html/../src/MyProject..'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /home/p/prognoex/prognoex.beget.tech/public_html/index.php on line 5

Как заставить работать?

Comment: Заставить работать, можно прописав правильный путь, вы сами не замечаете, что у вас подключается?

Comment: А что за курс по ооп? Скинь ссылку.

Comment: Вообще очень странно:
Ошибка в директории:
/home/p/prognoex/prognoex.beget.tech/ а пытаетесь вы подключить файл из директории  /home/p/site/site.beget.tech/

Comment: Кто про курс спрашивал: webshake.ru Сколько курсов не проходила, везде какие-то косяки, которые авторы нефига не помогают решать. :(

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой "Спасибо". Вместо этого лучше проставьте галку на ответе, который вам помог больше всего.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myAutoLoader(string $className)
{
    $className = str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$className);
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../src/' . $className . '.php';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Функция Ivan Matthews работает!

Comment: хостинг на линуксе, OpenServer на виндовсе: если для виндовс и слеши и регистр пути файла не важны (D:\path/to/MyFile и D:\path\to\myfile - для виндовс один и тот же файл), то на линуксе все левые слеши нужно заменить на правые (с \ на /)